# How to print table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I found this code to print in Javascript.

```
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
```

The element ID "printTable" is the ID of the table that I want to print but unfortunately it only prints out the contents of the table and not the style of the table. I just want to have borders on it so that it is easier to read in print. Can anyone help me?

Comment: As dimshik stated in his answer, when you open up a new window - you're not carrying across any CSS or JavaScript files that you had on your main page, it's like an empty new instance/window. So that's why your table styles is quite bare; you'll need to add CSS Styles.

Comment: so how do I attach css files to be carried to the new window? i tried dimshiks approach but i got thick borders..

Comment: that's because he's applying standard HTML borders with the `border="1"` attribute, although this is an old & unstandardised way of applying borders with HTML4-5 (Afterall, it was just an simple example). You could either: inject a stylesheet to the head of the new window, or add inline styles to the table.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is your code in a jsfiddle example. I have tested it and it looks fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/dimshik/9DbEP/4/

I used a simple table, maybe you are missing some CSS on your new page that was created with JavaScript.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: thanks,. i tried and it work but how do i make the borders thinner?

Comment: there is this oldschool tool for table styling :)

[Table Style](http://www.somacon.com/p141.php)

Comment: i always do have respect fo rpeople who add jiffdle links

Comment: what about adding header and footer

Comment: What should be done if we want to put styles from CSS files?.. instead of inline CSS..

Answer (score 9):

One cheeky solution :

```
  function printDiv(divID) {
        //Get the HTML of div
        var divElements = document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML;
        //Get the HTML of whole page
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
        document.body.innerHTML = 
          "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
          divElements + "</body>";
        //Print Page
        window.print();
        //Restore orignal HTML
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;

    }
```

HTML :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="printablediv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Blue; height: 200px">
        Print me I am in 1st Div
    </div>
    <div id="donotprintdiv" style="width: 100%; background-color: Gray; height: 200px">
        I am not going to print
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print 1st Div" onclick="javascript:printDiv('printablediv')" />
</form>
```

Comment: Well that's a smart way to save some time

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a jQuery plugin to do that

[jQuery PrintPage plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin)

[Demo](http://www.position-absolute.com/creation/print/)

Comment: its OK. its just an extra option

Answer (score 5):

My fellows,

In January 2019 I used a code made before:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">   
    function imprimir() {
        var divToPrint=document.getElementById("ConsutaBPM");
        newWin= window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }
</script>
```

To undestand: ConsutaBPM is a DIV which contains inside phrases and tables. I wanted to print ALL, titles, table, and others. The problem was when TRIED to print the TABLE...

The table mas be defined with BORDER and CELLPADDING:

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='1' id='Tablbpm1' >
```

It worked fine!!!